# How to change duplicate values to unique values in a column using by stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have to change RowSpan value if OccupationalInjuryId's duplicate value exists. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Should I use T-SQL or `#temporary` table structure. But I couldn't figure out how to fix. For example there are two values with `OccupationalId = 1100` and both rowspan's are 2. It should be 1 for second value's RowSpan no.

My SQL query:

```
select *
from    
    (select 
        Row_Number() over (order by oi.Id) as RowNo,
        oid.OccupationalInjuryId
     from 
        OTH_OccupationalInjury oi
     left join 
        OTH_OccupationalInjuryDetail oid on oi.Id = oid.OccupationalInjuryId
     where 
        1 = 1) t1
left join
    (select
        count(OccupationalInjuryId) end as RowSpan,
        oid.OccupationalInjuryId
     from 
        OTH_OccupationalInjury oi
    left join 
        OTH_OccupationalInjuryDetail oid on oi.Id = oid.OccupationalInjuryId
    where 
        1=1
    group by 
        OccupationalInjuryId
    having
        (Count(OccupationalInjuryId) > 1) ) t2 on t1.OccupationalInjuryId = t2.OccupationalInjuryId
END
```

Comment: What if there are three duplicate value?

Comment: Right. Only First value would be unique . Others would be 1.

Comment: How you know which is unique of 2 same values? But overall use `Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY  OccupationalInjuryId ORDER BY something)` and all with 1 put as 1 all other as you wish ;)

Comment: So, it will always be 2? And other row value will be minus one? I think Darka is saying is correct approach. Try it, and you will get the solution yourself.

Comment: It doesnt matter which one is unique. Just I need to get first row's RowSpan value within duplicate values. I tried your solution, but I couldnt see any difference.

Comment: Nope. It might me 3,4,5 times duplicate values... Only the first one's rowSpan will be needed for me. Others must be 1 or null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you correctly, you only care about first RowSpan value for each OccupationalInjuryId and for others you want 1. If I am wrong, correct me.

So, Can you try something like :

```
DECLARE @BaseTable TABLE(ID INT, OccupationalInjuryId INT, RowSpan INT)
INSERT INTO @BaseTable (ID, OccupationalInjuryId, RowSpan)
SELECT 1, 1100, 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1100, 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1099, 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 1099, 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 1106, NULL

SELECT 
  ID, 
  OccupationalInjuryId, 
  CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN RowSpan ELSE 1 END AS RowSpan 
FROM
(
  SELECT ID, OccupationalInjuryId, RowSpan, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OccupationalInjuryId, RowSpan ORDER BY ID) AS rn FROM @BaseTable
) tmp
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. your solution seems like good, but not exactly what I am looking for. Your result => OccupationalInjuryId , RowSpan == 1099, 2 - 1099,3 ... It should be 1099,1 - 1099,3 . Thats why I am not sure to use  "partition by" function. If I find a way, I'll share it. However, I'll mark as correct answer.

Comment: Oh wait, I changed your way a bit. Then It works. Sorry my bad. Thank you very much!